# closing a window after Response.End

Tags: asp.net, listview, response

e.g. I have a form with a `ListView` that is in edit mode.
Something happens so that the table the Listview is using is no longer available.
I just want to be able to close the window if the user hits 'save'.

`In Page_Load`, I check if the table is available, if not, I call `RegisterClientScriptBlock(type,name,"window.close()").`  However, processing still occurs, and it goes to L`istView1_ItemUpdating event`.

In `Page_Load`, if the table doesn't exist, I can call Response.End to stop processing, however, the window still stays up since the script never registered.

Any way to stop processing and close the window without having to put a custom `IsTableValid()` check in all of my methods?

Comment: Have you tried using Response.Flush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution, kludgey, but can be used elsewhere:

`Response.Redirect("close.html")`

where `close.html` just has

```
  <script>
  window.close();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by Oded doesn't work from Page_Load, I don't know why. The answer provided by eych works. Yet, if you don't want to keep an extra html file and make a redirect, you can use something like:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx) the response to send all data to the browser before ending it:

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock(type,name,"window.close()")
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

You may want to [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clear.aspx) the response before registering the script, in order to ensure that there is nothing else in the response buffer.

There are also `ClearHeaders` and `ClearContent` methods if you only want to clear one and not the other.

Comment: tried this, but it still leaves an empty window up. (also tried Clear)

Comment: @eych - What does the HTML source look like? Are you getting any javascript errors? Some windows cannot be closed from script (for instance, normally, only if you opened the window with a script, could you close it by script as well).

Comment: window was originally opened with script, and there are no javascript errors.  I have a separate 'Close' button that when clicked, also calls the same RegisterClientScript(...) method, and that works, closing the form [I guess since there's no more processing after the Button_Click].

Comment: @Oded - Which source?  Source of the blank window?  If you need the source of the original, it is on another machine.  Anything particular you're looking for?

Comment: @eych - If you are getting an empty HTML page, nothing in it, then the script was not output to the page. I want to confirm that, that's all.

Comment: yes, it's empty...<!DOCTYPE...><HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY></BODY></HTML>

Comment: @eych - try having *Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.close();</script>");* maybe RegisterClientScriptBlock is being ignored due to Ending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Microsoft themselves [say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) that Response.End is there only for backward compatibility:

> This method is provided only for
>   compatibility with ASP—that is, for
>   compatibility with COM-based
>   Web-programming technology that
>   preceded ASP.NET

Not sure it will solve your problem but at least Microsoft won't have an excuse.. :)